# Parsing JSON object in Android Studio, Object not updating in try block

Tags: android, json, parsing, try-catch

I am working on a college project and I am trying to parse timetable information from an api that appears like this:

```
"1474239600000" : {
    "courseCode" : "CASE4",    
    "moduleCodes" : [ "CareersService" ],
    "moduleDescription" : "Careers Svs. slots in ALL Year 4s",    
    "startTime" : 1474286400000,     
    "endTime" : 1474290000000,  
    "locations" : [ "GLA.XG21", "GLA.Q119" ],        
    "type" : "SEMINAR"   
    }
```

I am running parsing code in the AsyncTask of an android activity. Here is the code I have done to do this:

```
protected Lecture doInBackground(String... urls) {   

Lecture lec = new Lecture();

try{    

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(    
    new FileReader("json.txt"));      
    String inputLine;          
    String content = "";

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {    
        content = content + inputLine;    
        System.out.println(inputLine);    
        //Log.d("INPUT:",inputLine);    
    }


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
    String courseCode = obj.getString("courseCode");

    String moduleDescription = obj.getString("moduleDescription");    

    String type = obj.getString("type");
    lec = new Lecture(courseCode,"TEST",moduleDescription,type);    
    }catch(Exception e){    
        Log.e("JSON PARSER:","CATCH ERROR");    
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }    
    return lec;    
}
```

When I return the Lecture object lec, It is not showing the values assigned in the try block but the default values that were set to Lecture.

I would appreciate any help possible,

Thanks,
Ryan.

Comment: is the JSON described in your issue complete? If so then it's malformed. I assume you are also getting an exception and the application never runs the whole try block.

Comment: Do you have any idea's as to why this application is not entering the try block?

Comment: @BrickTop  
Do you have any idea's as to why this application is not entering the try block?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. Change your JSON to the following structure then your code should work:

```
{
    "courseCode" : "CASE4",    
    "moduleCodes" : [ "CareersService" ],
    "moduleDescription" : "Careers Svs. slots in ALL Year 4s",    
    "startTime" : 1474286400000,     
    "endTime" : 1474290000000,  
    "locations" : [ "GLA.XG21", "GLA.Q119" ],        
    "type" : "SEMINAR"   
}
```

A JSON key can't be the root element of the JSON document, which is in your case "1474239600000". Because of this you are most likely receiving an exception because the JSONObject can't be created.

Comment: Hi @BrickTop I have removed the JSON key but I am still unable to enter the try block

Comment: Okay, can you please post the complete AsyncTask, the activity you are calling the AsyncTask and the complete content of the json.txt. Addtionally if there is an exception also post the StackTrace. Did you already try to debug it?